# Filter by user property doesn't work in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

In order to test how the filter by user property works , I've did the bellow test :

**1**. I've run the bellow code, which set user **property favorite_food** to **pizza** . and send event called **test_audience_event2** . it should associate the property to the event . right ?

FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString("pizza", forName: "favorite_food2")
             FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName("test_audience_event2", parameters: nil)

after 24 hours, i succeed to see **test_audience_event2** as you can see in the bellow picture:
[image]

**2**. Now I've set filter = **userProperty.favorite_food2.pizza**, but i got nothing as i can see in the bellow picture. why ?
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you register the user property in the User Properties tab well in advance of running the code which called setUserPropertyString and logEventWithName?

Comment: @SteveGanem could this also be because there are simply not enough (i.e. < 10) matching users for the audience?

Comment: @SteveGanem thank you for your comment. yes i did

Comment: Do the results look the same if you include Today in the date range?  Note that "Last 30 Days" does not include Today.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the threshold only applies for Audience filters.  This is a User Property filter.

Comment: Hello Guys , do you need any more info ? to know what's happening ? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Audiences have a 10 users threshold before showing data, maybe filtering also have a 10 users threshold ? Have you try launching your on 10 different device, or install-launch-uninstall-reinstall etc 10 times on one devices ?

Comment: thank you for your answer,yes i have contacted firebase team and they told there should be at least 10 users.